# returning a value in a function in a class

Tags: php, yii

I have a class to do some simple calculations.

```
class CalculatorsController extends Controller {

   public function actionroadTaxCalculator() {
           // form inputs are valid, do something here
            $cc = $this->rem_commas(trim($_calc['cc']));
            $sOptions = trim($_calc['fuel']);
            $location = trim($_calc['location']);
            $use = trim($_calc['use']);

           $this->roadtaxCalculation(array('cc' => $cc, 'fuel' => $sOptions, 'location' => $location, 'use' => $use), true);
  }
   /*
     * Where all the roadtax calculation happens
     * 
     */
     public static function roadtaxCalculation($arr, $isAjax = true) {
               $roadtax = ($sOptions == "petrol") ? 55 : 55;
               CalculatorsController::fuel($roadtax, $isAjax);
      }



   /*
     * function to format and echo road tax
     */ 
    public function fuel($RoadTax, $isAjax = true)
    {
        $RoadTax = number_format(round($RoadTax, 2), 2);
        //TODO: add list of cars matching CC
        $matches = '';

        if (!empty($isAjax))
        {
            echo CJSON::encode(array(
                                    'rtax'=> $RoadTax,
                                    'matches'=> $matches,
                      ));

            Yii::app()->end();
        }
        else
        {
            return $RoadTax;
        }
     }
}
```

the `roadtaxCalculation()` function has been simplified to this question, but basically it calls `fuel()` to later return the calculations. which it doesn't but when i `echo` it does work.

Comment: When calling a static function there's no class instance created. `how come i can't call` - read OOP manual section.

Comment: Do you know the difference between static and non static methods?

Comment: @u_mulder well even when i remove `static` the `return $RoadTax;` still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define method as static (just like you did with `roadtaxCalculation`) you are not allowed to use `$this`. Static methods are not bound to any instance of class `CalculatorsController`. In other words you can use it without object and that's why you can't use `$this`. What's more `fuel` must be static too.

And you have `return` statement in `else` so if you can see echoed text `else` won't be executed.

Comment: but in the else, `echo $RoadTax;` works. not `return $RoadTax;`

Comment: where do you check returned value?

Comment: in the `if-else` statement in the `fuel()` function

Comment: add `return` before `CalculatorsController::fuel($roadtax, $isAjax);` in `public static function roadtaxCalculation`